# Using a pair from a dataframe to transform another dataframe

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, which data I have to tidy. One that has the data to transform:

```
df <- data.frame(age=c("(0,5]", "(5,10]", "(10,15]", "(15,20]", "(20,25]", "(25,30]"),
           locNPlaces=c("AS, loc2", "aS, loc1", "AD, loc1",
                        "af, loc3", "loc4, AS", "AS, loc3"))
```

And another with the id and names of the values

```
idPlaces <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
           places=c("AS", "AD", "AF", "BA", "BC", "BD"))
```

I need to create a new column with the id of the places on df. It would look like this:

```
      age locNPlaces placesId
1   (0,5]   AS, loc2        1
2  (5,10]   aS, loc1        1
3 (10,15]   AD, loc1        2
4 (15,20]   AF, loc3        3
5 (20,25]   AS, loc4        1
6 (25,30]   AS, loc3        1
```

I wouldn't like to have to do it like this

```
df %>% mutate(placesId=
                     if(grepl("AS", locNPlaces, ignore.case=T)) 1,
                 if(grepl("AD", locNPlaces, ignore.case=T)) 2,
                 if(grepl("AF", locNPlaces, ignore.case=T)) 3)
```

since there are several of these cases and the don't have the same pairs, it would require me to redo this for each new set of pairs. Is there an easy way to use the pairs on a dataframe to create a new column?

Answer (score 1):

A way to do in base R would involve splitting `locNPlaces` into two parts, looking for the two letter code among the split words using `nchar`, and then using `grepl` to find out matches in `idPlaces`

```
sapply(strsplit(gsub(" ", "", (df$locNPlaces)), ","),
       function(a) idPlaces$id[which(grepl(pattern = a[nchar(a) == 2],
                                           x = idPlaces$places,
                                           ignore.case = TRUE))])
#[1] 1 1 2 3 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **edited** data, based on your comments

```
df <- data.frame(age=c("(0,5]", "(5,10]", "(10,15]", "(15,20]", "(20,25]", "(25,30]"),
   locNPlaces=c("loc2, AS", "aS, loc1", "AD, loc1",
                "AF, loc3", "AS, loc4", "AS, loc3"), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

First row is different

```
      age locNPlaces
1   (0,5]   loc2, AS
```

**Updated code** using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   separate(locNPlaces,", ",into=c("places","loc")) %>% 
   gather(key,value,c(places,loc)) %>%
   mutate(key=ifelse(grepl("loc",value),"loc","places")) %>%
   spread(key,value) %>%
   mutate(places=toupper(places)) %>% 
   left_join(idPlaces,by="places")
```

Output

```
      age  loc places id
1   (0,5] loc2     AS  1
2 (10,15] loc1     AD  2
3 (15,20] loc3     AF  3
4 (20,25] loc4     AS  1
5 (25,30] loc3     AS  1 
6  (5,10] loc1     AS  1
```

Comment: I made a mistake with the locNPlaces column. The places value wasn't supposed to always be before the comma. But otherwise it's a good solution.

Comment: ?? Does my answer not work for your specific case? Did you update your input data?

Comment: It works, just not for all values, since some could be `AF, loc3`, while others are `loc5, AD`. It's a mess of data source what I'm dealing with.

Comment: Is the first row Id supposed to have NA?

Comment: No...sorry, I didn't run it with `left_join`...I also get `NA` for the first row when I use `left_join`...I'll have to investigate

Comment: Edited so that the first row returns the right value

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use a look-up table type method with `match` like this:

```
idPlaces$id[match(toupper(substr(as.character(df$locNPlaces), 1, 2)),
                  as.character(idPlaces$places))]
[1] 1 1 2 3 1 1
```

Here, `match` selects the index (row number) of idPlaces according to the values that occur in `df$places`. This index is used to extract the values from `idPlaces$id`. `toupper`, `substr`, and `as.character` convert the factor variables into the desired character vectors that are used for matching.